# Using multiple simultaneous tests using Selenium IDE

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-ide, simultaneous

I have written a simple test for my website. The test simply search for a word in my search page and waits for results.

What I need is to run the same test 40 times simultaneously to mimic a situation where 40 users are searching for the same word at the same time.

Basically I want to know how to run them simultaneously not in a queue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is Selenium RC and Selenium Grid as Silenium IDE is quite limited on automated testing. RC allows you to run remote selenium tests (tho rc can run locally too) and grid allows you to simplify the access to all running rcs.

You need 40 clients at once. If you are using selenium-rc you can start severall clients simultaniously by configuring them to run on different ports. After that you have to start your test 40 times at once. That is the tricky part depending on what framework you are using to launch the tests.

I would suggest JMeter for load-test like situations. It is quite easy to setup and you can configure how many simulated users you want on your website at once. JMeter works fine for manuell tests and for automated tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't really understand what you mean by "That is the tricky part depending on what framework you are using to launch the tests.". in Selenium IDE nothing was mentioned about a framework. I used to write tests directly in the IDE. What is the framework used for ?

Comment: Thats more for automated tests. Like using PHPUnit or JUnit to launch your tests. It is not possible with Selenium IDE as far as I know. You should use JMeter instead.

Comment: Don't mind to ask in the comments here if you run into any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind but I guess you need to do that in Jmeter, actually what you are trying to do is part of Load/Stress where number of user tries to do some certain action simultaneously. Have a look a Jmeter.